# Create a .deb package from a QT apllication

Tags: qt, ubuntu, installation, libraries, deb

I have a QT application and I've been trying to build a .deb package to install in on Ubuntu.

I've been able to create the .deb package and install on that OS, but I'm not able to modify the path of the libraries that I need to run the application.

Is there a way to change the paths to those libraries to a flder that I have next to my application folder? I have tried with export LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable but it hasn't worked.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/274311/make-a-debian-package-deb-from-a-qt-project   maybe that could help?!

Comment: Wouldn't a .deb just install them to /usr/lib?